# Edit Item button on Modern SP Lists Redirects to Version Files (_.000)

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

Suddenly the edit button on all lists that I frequent are redirecting me to what seem to be version files for my list item instead of the edit view of my infopath form.

No one else in my organization is experiencing this.

Classic sharepoint works as expected... any ideas how to stop this?

[image: Selecting Edit] [image: Redirected here]

Comment: Looks like something you should open a support case to Office 365 support about